# Error: _sre.SRE_Pattern is not iterable ,I am using re.compile() to get the strings by comparing begining values and getting this errror

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I have so many codes in a icode but many of that codes start with the same number

for example 3435435353544,
3435435878993,
3435435453535....
i have 4 types like above, need to define it with a name using the if clause

My code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import awswranger as wr
import re

pattern1=re.compile(r'^3233443446')
pattern2=re.compile(r'^3234444233')
pattern3=re.compile(r'^3242444233')
pattern4=re.compile(r'^7634726472')

def get_match_codes(icode):
    try:
       if icode in pattern3 or icode in pattern4:
          stype='straight'
       elif icode in pattern2 or icode in pattern1:
          stype='late'
       else:
          stype="none"
       return stype
    except Exception as e:
       return 'Error from get_match_codes' +str(e)
```

Comment: There's an unneeded `(` in `elif(pcode in ['232423423','234234234']:`

Comment: sry my bad...u can u see now

Comment: Instead of `icode in pattern3` use e.g. `pattern3.match(icode)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`icode in pattern3` doesn't do a regex match - you get a runtime error as you found.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=match#re.match

Instead use `pattern3.match(icode)` or `pattern3.search(icode)`

Also there's no obvious need for the try/except.

If using `re.match()` this only matches at the start of the string, as per the documentation, so you don't need the leading ^ in the re. Or use `re.search()` to find the regex anywhere in the string.

So your code becomes:

```
import re

pattern1=re.compile(r'^3233443446')
pattern2=re.compile(r'^3234444233')
pattern3=re.compile(r'^3242444233')
pattern4=re.compile(r'^7634726472')

def get_match_codes(icode):
    if pattern3.match(icode) or pattern4.match(icode):
        stype='straight'
    elif pattern2.match(icode) or pattern1.match(icode):
        stype='late'
    else:
        stype="none"
    return stype
       

print( get_match_codes("3233443446" ) )
```

Output:

```
 late
```

Also, please next time you ask a question make your code minimal (e.g. no unneeded imports) and executable - include a call to your function and some data for that call. These are to make yourself answerer-friendly - it's polite to make it as easy as possible for readers to help you and hopefully provide an answer - so making your code executable by copy/paste *without adding anything* you also help *yourself*.